# using each and map to modify a range of an array indices

Tags: ruby

The following code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a.each.map {|i| i = 0}  # or   b = a.map {|i| i = 0}  does the same thing
```

makes b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] as expected

Is there an equally succinct way to change a range of a? (ex: set a[2..4] to 0)

I have messed around in irb, but my code returns only the elements that were modified

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a[2..4].each.map {|i| i = 0}
```

makes b = [0, 0, 0], where as I am trying to make b = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here.

First: why are you turning the `Array` into an `Enumerator` and then `map` that `Enumerator` instead of just mapping the `Array` directly? I.e. why do you have

```
b = a.each.map {|i| i = 0 }
```

instead of just

```
b = a.map {|i| i = 0 }
```

Also, why are you assigning to the block local variable `i` but never actually using that variable? I.e. why don't you just do

```
b = a.map {|i| 0 }
```

Of course, now you aren't using `i` *at all* ...

```
b = a.map { 0 }
```

However, since the values of `b` actually have absolutely no relationship at all to the values of `a`, you might just as well do

```
b = [0] * a.size
```

The same questions basically apply also to your second code example. Again, you completely *ignore* the elements of `a`, so using `map` simply makes no sense whatsoever. You can just do

```
(b = a.dup)[2..4] = [0] * 3
```

Or slightly more readable broken up into two expressions

```
b = a.dup
b[2..4] = [0] * 3 # or ... = [0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: The [0] * 3 expansion was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Another way to write `[0] * 3` would be `Array.new(3, 0)`